# Google App Engine Pricing

Tags: google-app-engine

I am having trouble understanding the pricing of Google App Engine.
Here is the price:
https://cloud.google.com/pricing/

As It says, for paid plan, it costs $0.08 / hour for On-Demand Front End Instances. What does that mean?

1. It means if your app scales to 5 instances for 10 hours, you only
   have to pay $0.08 * 10 = $0.8. (No matter how many instances you
   need, you pay by hours).
2. It means if your app scales to 5 instances for 10 hours, you have to
   pay $0.08 * 5 * 10 = $4

Which way of understanding is correct?

Comment: Not sure this question is appropriate for stackoverflow (not a programming question). Better suited to StackApps.

Comment: hey, there are many developers can answer this question. The Google App Engine Team has chosen Stack Over Flow the main support channel. I think the question should be here because it suites best. Delegating it to the other sites seems a little too rigid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the second one is right.
+ you pay a few cents for every instance start (don't remember how much)
and you have 28 instance hours free per day.